# Load cross-compiled libraries with python ctypes.cdll

Tags: python-2.7, dll, shared-libraries, cross-compiling, ctypes

Using Python-2.7.15 32b (x86_64 Ubuntu OS) for reasons...

The typical way to open a shared library using `ctypes` is:

`cdll.libx = cdll.LoadLibrary('/path/to/libx.so')`

However this outputs `OSError` when library is for another system type (e.g. cross-compiled ARM lib on x86_64 Ubuntu)

`OSError: /path/to/libx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

What is the canonical way to open a cross-compiled library in python2.7?

Comment: The architecture of a shared lib (*.so*) must match the one of the process that tries to load it.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your comment. That is the case using ctypes.cdll. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: No, this is in general. `ctypes.cdll` is just an interface to *Python*, and falls under the same rule. You must load and make use of your *ARM* built lib, from an "*ARM* process" that runs on an *ARM* device (could be physical or virtual or some kind of an emulator).

Comment: something similar to this maybe (d00ks), that can parse/load/run ARM libs,  This module seems to operate on the assembly instruction level. One that I'm looking for should parse through actual object files: https://github.com/sipefree/d00ks